# Regex to search variable assignment

Tags: regex, search, sublimetext2

I have a directory that contains a couple hundred files full of codes (PHP, HTML, CSS, Jquery, etc.) that I want to search. There are old codes in these files that made use of `and` and `or` instead of `&&` and `||` respectively.

I'm using Sublime Text 2 for my text editor and I did a Find in Folder search but I want to narrow down the result further so that it only shows me lines where a variable is assigned a value using `and` or `or`.

```
$is_valid = $is_active and !$is_deleted;
```

I know that I can do a search using regex in Sublime Text 2 but I don't do regular expressions so I haven't really tried anything yet.

#### EDIT

The reason I want to narrow down the result is because all of the lines of codes I've seen so far are `if` statements

```
if($is_active and !$is_deleted) {}
```

And those shouldn't matter so I don't want to include those.

Comment: @chris85 Probably not, there might be some `(` and/or `)` in there as well or even mathematical operators but I just want to see if I could find any codes that make use of the syntax provided in my question because it will behave differently than expected. It doesn't have to be a complete search but I just want to be able to start somewhere.

Comment: wouldn't a grep command be better for this?

Comment: @chris85 I could confirm that your regex works on that format but could it be modified so that a variable is on the left side of the `=` operator (with or without space in between) and then the keywords `and` or `or` found anywhere in the right side of the `=` operator?

Comment: @chris85 My problem with your regex is that it doesn't match `$is_valid = (($cost + $tax) > 20) and ($tax < 3);` Basically I don't care about the syntax after the `=` operator - as long as `and` or `or` is found after and `=` and then assigned to a variable located before `=` that's what I want.

Comment: @chris85 There you go, that's much better. Care to put that as an answer?

Comment: Okay, moved it down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore the `if` lines using the PCRE verbs, you can then search for a variable assignment and the `or` or `and`.

```
^\s*if.*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\$\w+\s*=.* (and|or) .*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qZ0uzI/5

Note the `\$\w+` isn't actually a valid variable name check. You could modify that with a character class and the PHP specs for valid variable names.